# API Logging and MYSQL Load

Tags: mysql

I made an api and am logging all the requests to it.

When someone hits the api, there is an insert and an update (in order to record the api response code)

During testing the api log is around 200k records, this might go to a few million records very quickly.

Does this kind of logging, ie insert and update, put alot of pressure on the server?

My concern is that mysql will get overloaded due to logging so not sure if I should trim the logs every 7 days or something.

Comment: determine too how you will use this info later, or if you are a collector of useless info. You could keep it in another db, `select * into outfile` , and truncate. Depending on your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few million records won't hurt the database storage-wise. I've got MySQL tables with hundreds of millions of rows and they work fine when indexed. I would consult the MySQL manual for [Data Manipulation Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html) and [Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html) to see if what you're doing is going to stretch performance limits.

[MySQL's indexing guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) if you'd like to know more.

If you're worried about overloading your DB, you could write a `cron` job to backup your database each day and then just truncate/load after hitting a certain row count or time of day or whatever. You would then have a backup of all the records that you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. When you say "indexed" do you mean with a primary key? (Excuse my ignorance for lack of knowledge on the terminology)

Comment: I added a link to the MySQL index documentation, but yes a `PRIMARY KEY` is an example of an index for a table. There are other indexes that you can create on tables as well that will help your queries run much faster with millions of rows. :)